# How to take a screenshot of a bunch of labels and other trivial widgts in Qt and save it to a file at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt

Alright so i was working on a C++ project for school which required me to create an interactive timetable. So i implemented this in Qt and the implementation turned out to be quite successful.

I am now on the final stage where i want to take a **screenshot of a particular part of the window which contains the timetable and store it as an image.**

[image: Here is a picture of the particular window i have Desgined]

Now the problem is that this is **not a single container**. The entries are actually **labels** and i set attributes and wrote code for each of them individually. So i guess i cant use the Pixmap property to grab the widget or something as there is NO widget.

I need the part inside the border to be captured as an image and i want to store it on my PC as a jpeg file when the generate button is pressed. I know how to do the latter but how do i GET the image and store it?

Here is the code for the particular form/window. Not sure it will help but still..

```
#include "student_tt.h"
#include "ui_student_tt.h"
#include "dialog.h"
#include "QListWidgetItem"
#include "QListWidget"
#include "QLCDNumber"
#include <QString>
#include <string>
#include <QMessageBox>

void Student_TT::checkCredits()
{
    int cnt=0;
    if(!ui->m1->text().contains('-'))
    {
        cnt+=5;
    }
    if(!ui->m1_2->text().contains('-'))
    {
        cnt+=3;
    }
    if(!ui->m1_3->text().contains('-'))
    {
        cnt+=3;
    }
    if(!ui->m1_4->text().contains('-'))
    {
        cnt+=4;
    }
    if(!ui->m1_5->text().contains('-'))
    {
        cnt+=2;
    }
    QString x=QString::number(cnt);
    ui->ccount->setText(x);
    if(cnt>=10&&cnt<=15)
    {
        ui->tryx->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green}");
        ui->gbutton->setEnabled(1);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->tryx->setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : red}");
        ui->gbutton->setEnabled(0);
    }



    }

    Student_TT::Student_TT(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Student_TT)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    Student_TT::~Student_TT()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void Student_TT::on_Student_TT_accepted(QString a,QString b,QString c)
    {

        ui->name->setText("NAME: "+a);
        ui->reg->setText("REG.NO: "+b);
        ui->stm->setText("STREAM: "+c);
    }

    void Student_TT::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
    {
        if(item->isSelected())
        {
            QString a=ui->m1->text();

            if(a!=item->text())
            {

                QString x1=item->text();
                ui->sub1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : deepskyblue; }");
                ui->w1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : deepskyblue; }");
                ui->f1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : deepskyblue; }");//Setting colours to labels
                ui->lab1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : deepskyblue; }");
                ui->lab1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : deepskyblue; }");
                ui->m1->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->w1->setText(x1);
                ui->f1->setText(x1);
                ui->lab1->setText(x1+"L");
                ui->lab1_2->setText(x1+"L");

            }
            else
            {
                ui->sub1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : black; }");
                QString x1=ui->m1_8->text();//Unused
                ui->m1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->w1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->f1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");//Setting colours to labels
                ui->lab1->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->lab1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->w1->setText(x1);
                ui->f1->setText(x1);
                ui->lab1->setText(x1);
                ui->lab1_2->setText(x1);

            }
        }
        checkCredits();//updating credits
    }



    void Student_TT::on_listWidget_2_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
    {
        if(item->isSelected())
        {
            QString a=ui->m1_2->text();//Its Physics


            if(a!=item->text())
            {

                QString x1=item->text();
                ui->sub2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : orange; }");
                ui->tu1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : orange; }");
                ui->th1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : orange; }");//Setting colours to labels
                ui->lab2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : orange; }");
                ui->lab21->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : orange; }");
                ui->m1_2->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->tu1_2->setText(x1);
                ui->th1_2->setText(x1);
                ui->lab2->setText(x1+"L");
                ui->lab21->setText(x1+"L");
            }
            else
            {
                QString x1=ui->m1_8->text();//Unused
                ui->sub2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : black; }");
                ui->m1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->tu1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->th1_2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");//Setting colours to labels
                ui->lab2->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->lab21->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1_2->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->tu1_2->setText(x1);
                ui->th1_2->setText(x1);
                ui->lab2->setText(x1);
                ui->lab21->setText(x1);


            }
        }
    checkCredits();//updating credits
    }


    void Student_TT::on_listWidget_3_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
    {
        if(item->isSelected())
        {
            QString a=ui->m1_3->text();//Its Chemistry


            if(a!=item->text())
            {

                QString x1=item->text();
                ui->sub3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1_3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : magenta; }");
                ui->w1_3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : magenta; }");
                ui->f1_3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : magenta; }");
                ui->lab32->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : magenta; }");
                ui->lab33->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : magenta; }");
                ui->m1_3->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->w1_3->setText(x1);
                ui->f1_3->setText(x1);
                ui->lab32->setText(x1+"L");
                ui->lab33->setText(x1+"L");
            }
            else
            {
                QString x1=ui->m1_8->text();//Unused
                ui->sub3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : black; }");
                ui->m1_3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->w1_3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->f1_3->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");//Setting colours to labels
                ui->lab32->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->lab33->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1_3->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->w1_3->setText(x1);
                ui->f1_3->setText(x1);
                ui->lab32->setText(x1);
                ui->lab33->setText(x1);


            }
        }

        checkCredits();//updating credits
    }


    void Student_TT::on_listWidget_4_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
    {
        if(item->isSelected())
        {
            QString a=ui->m1_4->text();//Maths
            if(a!=item->text())
            {

                QString x1=item->text();
                ui->sub4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1_4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : darkcyan; }");
                ui->tu1_4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : darkcyan; }");
                ui->th1_4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color :  darkcyan; }");
                ui->lab43->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color :  darkcyan; }");
                ui->lab44->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color :  darkcyan; }");
                ui->m1_4->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->tu1_4->setText(x1);
                ui->th1_4->setText(x1);
                ui->lab43->setText(x1+"L");
                ui->lab44->setText(x1+"L");
            }
            else
            {
                QString x1=ui->m1_8->text();//Unused
                ui->sub4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : black; }");
                ui->m1_4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->tu1_4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->th1_4->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");//Setting colours to labels
                ui->lab43->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->lab44->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
                ui->m1_4->setText(x1);//Setting text
                ui->tu1_4->setText(x1);
                ui->th1_4->setText(x1);
                ui->lab43->setText(x1);
                ui->lab44->setText(x1);


            }
        }
        checkCredits();//Updating Credits
    }

void Student_TT::on_pushButton_clicked()//Information
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Information"),tr("1. There will be credits for each course marked in '[]'\n2. Credits may be thought of as 'weightage'. More the credits, more important the subject will be.\n3. You must select a minimum of 10 credits and a maximum of 15 credits\n4. To select or change your course, just CLICK on the Course Code"));
}

void Student_TT::on_listWidget_5_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    if(item->isSelected())
    {
        QString a=ui->m1_5->text();//Maths
        if(a!=item->text())
        {

            QString x1=item->text();
            ui->sub5->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green; }");
            ui->m1_5->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : lime; }");
            ui->f1_5->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : lime; }");
            ui->m1_5->setText(x1);//Setting text
            ui->f1_5->setText(x1);
        }
        else
        {
            QString x1=ui->m1_8->text();//Unused
            ui->sub5->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : black;}");
            ui->m1_5->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green;}");
            ui->f1_5->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : green;}");
            ui->m1_5->setText(x1);//Setting text
            ui->f1_5->setText(x1);
        }
    }
    checkCredits();//Updating Credits
}
```

Notice that there are a a few componenets from other windows in the code but i guess the code doesn't really need to be understood. You can check each label being assigned colours in the 5 'ItemSelected' functions.

Comment: You mean to take screenshot of window inside Qt at runtime? Or with other software manualy?

Comment: Manually would me simple alt + prntscr and edit in paint. Lol

Comment: Ok, sorry for dumb question. :D

Comment: "there is NO widget" There certainly is a widget, unless you're using a bare `QWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me.  I just settled with the complete screenshot.

```
 QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget( w );
 pixmap.save("*folder location*/*file name*.jpg");
```

Answer (score 3):

Take look at [QWidget::grab](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) method if you are using Qt 5.0 and above, otherwise take a look at [QPixmap::grabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWidget) method.

> If the widget has any children, then they are also painted in the appropriate positions.

Comment: @bholagabbar what container do you have? The code you posted works with `ui`, so you have some sort of container created with Designer. I think ui is derived from QDialog, check the autogenerated code.

Comment: @bholagabbar "I don't HAVE a widget" Where do all these QLabels live, then? Of course they are in a parent widget. Where else would they be?

Comment: @bholagabbar "All of these are labels on a form." The "form" is just a widget, so what's your problem, then?

Comment: I need a 'part' of the widget?

Comment: @bholagabbar What's the problem with cutting out just the part that you need out of a larger pixmap? Sure, you get the whole widget, then cut out the part that has the coordinates of the timetable itself.

Comment: Sorry about the 'no container' thing. My concepts were a bit distorted. I get the meaning now

Comment: @Kuba Ober: I'll try that out. Thanks

Comment: @KubaOber What if using a container widget to hold those labels that OP wants to save as image, and call `QWidget::grab` on the container widget. Would it be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. (Code not tested, but should give the idea, where to get the widget.)
`activeWindow` is your top-level widget.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QDateTime>

//...
//Somewhere in clicked-slot
QWidget * w = QApplication::activeWindow();
if(w)
{
  QPixmap scrshot = QPixmap::grabWidget( w );
  scrshot.save( QString("%1/%2.jpg")
    .arg(QDesktopServices::storageLocation( QDesktopServices::DesktopLocation))
    .arg( QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyymmddThhMMss"))
  );    
}
```

If you have designed the GUI with QtCreator, you can check the widget name in property editor and call e.g.

```
QPixmap::grabWidget( ui->myTableWidget );
```

Comment: Seems legit. I'll try it out and get back to you